# adding a tabindex attr to a specific input

Tags: jquery

I have an issue i am trying to modify a form's tab order which the HTML is out of my control, so i need to modify the code with JQuery to make the form tab in a way that i want.

here is the html code i cant change:

```
<div class="form1">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input id="field1" class="field1" type="text" value="" name="Initials">
</div>
```

and i thought that this JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#field1").attr("tabindex","1");
});
```

would generate:

```
<div class="form1">
   <label>First Name</label>
   <input id="field1" class="field1" tabindex="1" type="text" value="" name="Initials">
</div>
```

yet i was wrog it did nothing.

there is alot more inputs i need to target and all with random ID's :(

---

Additional information.

the form is generated by (i have changed some of the values but hope it makes sense):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://XXX.com/widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var widget_config = {
   widgetId: 'XX',
   campaignId: 'XX',
   clientId: 'XX',
   trackingId: 'website',
   baseUrl: 'https://XXX.com'
}

var display_config7 = {
   cssId: 1,
   'background-color': '#',
   'font-family': 'Times New Roman',
   'color': '#000000',
   'font-size': '12px',
   'width': 400,
   'height': 600
}

widget.init('#widget_XXX', widget_config_XXX, display_config_XXX);

</script>
```

adding the JQuery to the page does not target this code generated so i tried adding it within the script itself which too did not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://XXX.com/widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var widget_config = {
   widgetId: 'XX',
   campaignId: 'XX',
   clientId: 'XX',
   trackingId: 'website',
   baseUrl: 'https://XXX.com'
}

var display_config7 = {
   cssId: 1,
   'background-color': '#',
   'font-family': 'Times New Roman',
   'color': '#000000',
   'font-size': '12px',
   'width': 400,
   'height': 600
}

widget.init('#widget_XXX', widget_config_XXX, display_config_XXX);

$("#field-Initials").attr("tabindex","1");
$("#field-Surname").attr("tabindex","2");

</script>
```

Comment: How do you know that it did nothing? That code sets the `tabindex` attribute of your `#field1` element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> yet i was wrog it did nothing.

No, it does exactly what you expect it to do. It sets the `tabindex="1"` attribute to an element with `id="field1"`. It's just that it does it directly into the DOM. If you look at the source code of the page you will see the original HTML as sent by the server. Use a DOM inspecting tool such as [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see the modifications.

As far as the random ids are concerned, well, then it will depend on what order you would like to apply the tabindex. You could select all your input fields like this `$('input')` and then increment the tabindex but this way the index will be set in the same order in which inputs appear in the DOM so this might require tweaking based on your specific needs:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').attr('tabindex', function(index, attr) {
        return index + 1;
    });
});
```

Comment: i have tested my code on a test form and it works perfect (should have done this before). then i came to add this to the built page i need it to work on... and it did not work, it seems the problem is, is that the form itself is generated by JS/JQUEY from another site (its a widget i am pulling onto my page).

Is there a way to make this happen on the widget form generated by another site, i hope this makes sense. i have amended my initial question to shed some light

Comment: @sluap, no it doesn't make sense. There are many ways to do widgets. You will have to explain what mechanism is used exactly. If the widget inserts an iframe on another domain you will not be able to manipulate its contents due to the same origin policy restriction.

Comment: @sluap, does the widget add an iframe to your page?

Comment: nope it generates the code on the page, viewing the source in FB its there as if i built the form

Comment: PS. i can target the form with CSS to style it

Comment: @sluap, given the symptoms of your problem it looks like this widget includes data from a different domain that you cannot manipulate due to the same origin policy restriction.

Comment: thank you, for your time i will have a word with the company to see if i can get them to change this, again thank you for your time.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, I am trying to achieve similar task here. I would need to tweak to set tabindex in vertical order of the columns rather than the default horizontal way. Can you point out some source that will help me to get start ?